# ASP.NET MVC5 add authentication into an empty project

Tags: asp.net, authentication, owin

I've  created an empty asp.net mvc5 project, used EF with code first approach. How can I add OWIN authentication and store Users and Roles in my created database? How  can I customize OWIN authentication for my purpose?

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough. I try to explain. In my asp.net mvc5 empty project I used EF which generated DB for me.I want to add authentication functionality into my project. I read many articles how to work with Identity, but in all samples explained how to use local db and not existing db. I want to store information about Users in my existing DB not in local db. How

Comment: I don't know why down vote this question, I have similar issues.

Comment: I think your question is very valid. You can find some useful information in the link below, like adding the relevant NuGet packages and a script for creating the needed tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960433/adding-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-an-existing-project

Answer (score 0):

Look into Microsoft's Identity framework. You can the Nuget package Identity EntityFramework to your project.

Answer (score 0):

A good guide to setup a token based authentication: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid link only answers. While providing references is encouraged, please summarise the relevant parts of the link in your answers.