# how to use SignInAsync in webapi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to login user through webapi.
My apicontroller function is:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(string email, string password)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();
            UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ctx);
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(email, password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, true); // The name 'SignInAsync' does not exist in current context
                return Ok("OK");
            }
            return Ok("Error");
        }
```

I want to write methods of signup, login, and logout in webapi but i am stuck at `SignInAsync`. Am I missing library reference? Or how to use this in webapi?

Answer (score 1):

`SignInAsync` is a method of `SignInManager` class not controller class write this instead:

```
await HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .Get<ApplicationSignInManager>().SignInAsync(user, true, false);
```

Comment: `GetOwinContext` is not coming with `HttpContext.`. I have included namepace `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin`

Comment: You must install Microsoft. Owin.host.systemweb packege

Comment: Ok I have installed package using this command `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` but still `HttpContext.` is not showing `GetOwinContext` in  IntelliSense.

Comment: Did you configured Owin?

Comment: How to configure Owin?

Comment: Please read my earlier answer about [how to configuring Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960433/adding-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-an-existing-project/31963828#31963828). It is about MVC but you could do same in WebAPI too.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think the portion useful for me from answer is from "Add a class to App_Start folder" but a class is already added to app_Start folder named `Startup.Auth.cs`. On `ConfigureAuth` method of this class I am stuck on second line which is: `app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);` I don't know what to write instead of `AppUserManager` I have tried `UserManager` and `ApplicationUser` but none of them is working.

Comment: Could you please submit your `Startup.Auth` content?

Comment: sorry name of that file is `Startup.Auth.cs` and the class inside it is a partial class named `Startup`

Comment: this class has a method defined as: `public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);`

Comment: Why you are stuck? If you follow my instruction in the link. I mentioned how to create those classes. Are you using Identity's default template? Or installed after project creation?

Comment: I am using Identity default template. I don't know what to write instead of `AppUserManager` in `app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);`

Comment: If you are using default template. You must have `ApplicationUserManager` class in your project. So you could write `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create)`

Comment: No I don't have class of `ApplicationUserManager` instead I have `ApplicaitonUser` which is not working.  I am using asp.net Identity. When I created project I checked `Individual User Authentication`. After that I didn't make any changes in store or anywhere related to identity. I am using data-first approach.

Comment: So make new class which extends `UserManager<ApplicaitonUser>` just like I did in the post. In my post `AppUser` is actually your `ApplicaitonUser`. Also you could omit `AppRole` related parts since you already had.

Comment: Hi , In your solution I am stuck at `RoleStore` class. it says `the type or namespace RoleStore could not be found`.

Comment: Add `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` namespace

Comment: I have write the code as you said in answer but it says `System.web.httpContext does not contain definition for GetOwinContext` in webapi controller.

Comment: Make sure you added `Microsoft.Owin` namespace. Also you already installed `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` also because you are using WebAPI write `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext() ...` instead.