# How to add asp.net identity to existing web api project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have 2 projects in my solution. First one is simple mvc project and the other one is web api. There was no pre-written code in web api. I put all logics myself. Now I want to add asp.net identity in the web api project. How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: I've had this link for a while in case i encounter that problem. Not sure if is what you looking for but could give you a hint. http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Have a look at this answer: [Adding ASP.NET MVC5 Identity Authentication to an existing project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960433/adding-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-an-existing-project/31963828#31963828)

Comment: Did you already have any kind of authentication before?

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if that solves your problem? Please please please :D

Answer (score 2):

In your web api project, you can do this:
1. Create a DbContext class that looks like this:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public DataContext() : base("ConnectionStringLocal") { }
}
```

2. Add a connection string in your Web.config file
3. In Package manager console, do `Enable-Migrations`, `Add-Migration IdentityUpdate`, `Update-Database`. This will create a database that has asp.net identity built in.

Please let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was searching the web why the add-migration command didn't generate any of the built-in aspnet identity tables. I forgot to inherit from `IdentityDbContext`!