# my.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I tried to add ASP.NET identity to my existing MVC 5 project. I applied some articles about this issue.

I followed this articles:
[Adding ASP.NET MVC5 Identity Authentication to an existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960433/adding-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-an-existing-project)
http://www.yagizhanpala.com/asp_net_identity_ile_mvc_projede_uyelik_islemleri/

But after the implementation, I had same problem.

```
my.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
my.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

Note:I am using reverse code engineer to create model class.

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole 
{ 
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public ApplicationRole() { } 
    public ApplicationRole(string roleName, string description) : base(roleName) 
    { 
        this.Description = description; 
    } 
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Surname { get; set; } 
}
```

`OnModelcreating()` method includes:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LoginMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RegisterMap()); 
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your identity models are not inheriting from the correct base classes (e.g. from the linked question: `public class AppRole : IdentityRole
{ ... }`).

Comment: Could you please submit your `User` and `Role` classes code?

Comment: **public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
       
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ApplicationRole() { }

        public ApplicationRole(string roleName, string description)
            : base(roleName)
        {
            this.Description = description;
        }
    }**

Comment: _   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }_

Comment: And I tried another articles.Its Appuser and AppRole code:  public class Appuser:IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string MyExtraProperty { get; set; }  
    }

Comment: public class AppRole:IdentityRole
    {
        public AppRole() : base() { }
        public AppRole(string name) : base(name) { }
    }

Comment: I think, you have overridden your `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think to. onmodelcreating() method includes: protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LoginMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RegisterMap());
        }

Answer (score 1):

You must include `IdentityDbContext`'s configurations in your customized DBContext too. Simply call the parent's method in your overridden method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LoginMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RegisterMap()); 
}
```

Comment: I tried it but not worked. I had this error...An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: What is the exception's message?

Comment: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: Are you sure your DbContext is inherited from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` **not** from `DbContext` itself?

Comment: now, I had this error..................An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.....Could you suggest me another article or video for this issue

Comment: Your mentioned posts are fine. You probably missing something. What is the inner exception's message?