# EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' and 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net and I am trying to add ASP.NET identity to an existing project and I am following the solution provided answer here : [Adding ASP.NET MVC5 Identity Authentication to an existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960433/adding-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-an-existing-project)

But when I tried to add data migration I got the errors:
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

> **ManagementDashboard.DataLayer.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.**
>   ManagementDashboard.DataLayer.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
>   IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Could you show relevant code for `IdentityUserRole` class, since that seems to cause the error.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL This is what I am confused about. I am not able to find this class in my project as I didn't create it. I think it comes under Indentity.EntiryFramework Package

Comment: It is a long answer, but read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28532180/6741868) and if it is relevant, try to follow its suggestions.

Comment: Do you have primary key in database?