# how to add identity framework in existing mvc project of db first approach

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Hello everyone i just want to add identity framework on my existing web API project which have already a database by Entity framework database first approach.I want add identity framework table and functionality in my application please give me solution.

Comment: It is the same like adding to MVC app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960433/adding-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-an-existing-project

Comment: it's not working sir i fallow all step,i use database first approach for creating model class

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @cloudikka classes are not creating